# Find and click links in ugly table with Python and Selenium webdriver

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to get Selenium Webdriver to click **x** number of links in a table, and I can't get it to work. I can print the links like this:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[2]/tbody/tr/td/p/strong/a")
for i in range(0,len(links)):
    print links[i].text
```

But when I try to do a `links[i].click()` instead of printing, python throws me an error.

The site uses `JSP` and the `hrefs` of the links looks like this *"javascript:loadTestResult(169)"* 
This is a sub/sub-page and not possible to access by direct URL, and the table containing the links are very messy and large so instead of pasting the whole source here I saved the page on this url.

http://wwwe.aftonbladet.se/redaktion/martin/badplats.html
(I'm hunting the 12 blue links in the left column)

Any ideas?

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, to trigger happy.
Simple solution to my own problem:

```
linkList = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='loadTestResult']")
for i in range(0,len(linkList)):
        links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='loadTestResult']")
        links[i].click()
```